# Wrong resolution selected for my monitor each time I change my display setting

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04, display, display-resolution, lg

I have a Thinkpad E595 to which I connect a monitor (LG 32GK850F) via HDMI. My monitor has the native solution of 2560x1440 yet Ubuntu thinks it's capable of 3840x2160. This will of course look really bad as the refresh rate drops down to ~24Hz and overall everything becomes too small.

Now I often change my display settings, disabling one monitor, unplugging the external one, and on almost each change Ubuntu tends to forget that I want to run this monitor at 2560x1440 but will always go for 3840x2160 first.

It's annoying to manually change that.

How can I have my external monitor always be discovered as such that it will always use 2560x1440 resolution?

My display setting look like this, my monitor is discovered as `LG Eletronics 31`):

[image: Display setting of Ubuntu showcasing wrong setup]